# Can I safely and legally cover a tail light with red tape?

Tags: tail-lights

Is it safe and legal to cover just the light in the rear of my car with the red rear light tape in order to get it covered, or do I need to actually cover where the whole cover for the light was in order to be legal? There is only about 2 square inches of plastic left where the light used to be.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This question is really subjective to where you live. In Virginia (in the States) where I live, if you have a crack in the tail light, you have to replace it. Other States may not be that harsh. Other countries may not even require it at all.

Comment: I live in MN USA, almost the entire plastic is missing, and it will likely be totaled by insurance, and it's winter so the tail light is very cold right now. my insurance is taking over 2 weeks to decide what to do with it.

Comment: If it's a temporary thing, I'm sure you could "get away with it". You could also possibly put a red bulb in place of the original white bulb so the only light which comes out is red. This should suffice until you can get things sorted.

Comment: 2 lights, but i think i'll do that while car shopping (95 Jimmy)

Comment: As long as you haven't got time to get it replaced, covering it with a piece of tape at least keeps water out, which is good. Here in the Netherlands they wouldn't be so harsh about it, if the rest of the car doesn't look like it's falling apart.

Comment: You may need to consider "sharp edges" - this can present a danger to other road users and the police may be concerned if they see it...

Comment: @Bart i think you mean ice, and snow not water. the rest of the car was "drivable".

Comment: No, water. It'd take considerable effort to get snow in the rear light unit by just driving. Temperature difference makes moisture in the air condense at the lens of the light if there is a crack in it to allow exchange of air. Same happens to your windshield when it fogs up. That condsenation can transform into ice though.

Comment: when the whole light was taken out you can easily get water out of the light.